# How Do I change output Paper Size to A4 in React Native (expo android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, react-native

I am using React Native to make an Android App for the billing app and the output paper is 216mmX279mm which is not true PDF size,
I am using `expo-print`, `printToFileAsync` and  from the expo
I want PDF output exactly A4 size which 210mmX297mm

[image]

I looked it up at the expo `print` documentation
and it took me [.@page docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@pagehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) website
**How do I Change Output to A4 size**
I checked the [Documentation of](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/print/#fileprintoptions)  `print` and`FilePrintOptions`
it says

> Height of the single page in pixels. Defaults to 792 which is a height of US Letter paper format with 72 PPI.
> [image]

**So How Can I change default to A4 and increase DPI?**

Answer (score 1):

Found It.

```
const printToFile = async () => {

const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
  html, height:842, width:595
});
console.log('File has been saved to:', uri);
await shareAsync(uri, { UTI: '.pdf', mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
```

So, By default, `height:792, width:612`  of US letter paper at 72 PPI as I ask in the question,
`html` is a string and also takes `height` and `width` as `number`
as shown code block,

if you wanna change PPI change pixel size
for example
A4 72PPI = H842, W595
A4 150PPI = H1754,W1240
I think it only takes "px"